# ChatGPT discord bot responding to longer prompts (python)

Tags: discord.py

I have been working with a simple bot that allows for users to ask questions to chatgpt in discord and I have been struggling with this issue where certain prompts do not want to work. I get an error in discord saying the application did not respond, however it seems to only do this with longer responses. Ex: if i say good morning in the command it will give me a response. But if i ask a more complicated question that would give a longer response the bot doesn't respond.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import os

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_KEY')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name="ai", description="ask chatgpt anything")
async def ai(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(chatgpt_response(message))

def chatgpt_response(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=1,
        max_tokens=100
    ) 
    response_dict = response.get("choices")
    if response_dict and len(response_dict) > 0:
        prompt_response = response_dict[0]["text"]
    return prompt_response

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks for any help and sorry for asking such a newbie question.

I tried reworking the command and could not figure out how to get it to work using a command. I was able to get it to work by just typing /ai and then the prompt after in discord without actually using a slash command. I would like for it to work using a slash command.

Comment: Try to [`defer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=defer#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) your response

Comment: thanks @moinierer3000 that fixed it, new code looks like this:

`@bot.tree.command(name="ai", description="ask chatgpt anything")
async def ai(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    response = chatgpt_response(message)
    await interaction.followup.send(content=response)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a split message function to split the response.

```
def split_message(message, max_length):
    chunks = []
    while len(message) > max_length:
        chunk = message[:max_length]
        chunks.append(chunk)
        message = message[max_length:]
    chunks.append(message)
    return chunks
```

Then in your chatgpt function, simply call the split message function and then return the list of the message which is splited

```
def chatgpt_response(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=1,
        max_tokens=100
    ) 
    response_dict = response.get("choices")
    if response_dict and len(response_dict) > 0:
        prompt_response = response_dict[0]["text"]
        # Divide the message in parts of 2000 caracters
        chunks = split_message(prompt_response, 2000)
        return chunks
    return []
```

And finally in the command function send every part of the chunk list which is return

```
@bot.tree.command(name="ai", description="ask chatgpt anything")
async def ai(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
    responses = chatgpt_response(message)
    for response in responses:
        await interaction.response.send_message(response)
```

And this should work